# OpenMP for C++ class variables

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, class-variables

In c++ When we parallelize the loop using OpenMP directives, how should we do if we use a instance of the class in the loop and want to keep some members of the class to be private across all threads and others to be shared ?

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example? Your description is a bit confusing.

Comment: How are the data scope directives (e.g., firstprivate, shared, etc) not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

non-static class members cannot be individually chosen to be private or shared. You can only make the whole class object shared or private.